# an unknown error on a live server but the module works very well on localhost

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12, qweb

i am currently working on a project built using python and xml on odoo framework to generate a custom qwebreport with some data. .Its working very well on localhost where the port is being generated very well without any issues . But  when the module is run on a live server,it returns an error.The error is as follows:

```
Error:Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):  File 
 "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 347, in 
_compiled_fn    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)  
File "<template>", line 1, in template_4549_24  File " 
<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_23  File "<template>", 
line 3, in body_call_content_22TypeError: 'NoneType' object is 
not callable
During handling of the above exception, another exception 
occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):  File 
"/opt/odoo12/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1675, in 
report_download    response = self.report_routes(reportname, 
converter=converter, **dict(data))  File 
"/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap    
response = f(*args, **kw)  File 
"/opt/odoo12/addons/report_xlsx/controllers/main.py", line 43, in 
report_routes    reportname, docids, converter, **data  File 
"/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap    
 response = f(*args, **kw)  File 
  "/opt/odoo12/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1612, in 
  report_routes    pdf = 
  report.with_context(context).render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data) 
   [0]  File 
  
 "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", 
  line 721, in render_qweb_pdf    html = 
self.with_context(context).render_qweb_html(res_ids, data=data) 
[0]  File "/opt/odoo12/addons- 
enterprise/web_studio/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 18, in 
 render_qweb_html    return super(IrActionsReport, 
 self).render_qweb_html(docids, data)  File 
"/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", 
line 761, in render_qweb_html    return 
self.render_template(self.report_name, data), 'html'  File 
"/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", 
line 534, in render_template    return 
view_obj.render_template(template, values)  File 
"/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 
1324, in render_template    return 
self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)  
File "/opt/odoo12/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 315, 
 in render    return super(View, self).render(values, 
engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)  File 
"/opt/odoo12/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in 
render    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, 
engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)  File 
 "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 
 1333, in render    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, 
  qcontext)  File "/opt/odoo12/addons- 
  enterprise/web_studio/models/ir_qweb.py", line 43, in render    
   return super(IrQWeb, self).render(template, values=values, 
   **options)  File 
"/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 59, 
in render    result = super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, 
values=values, **context)  File 
"/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 275, in 
render    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, 
values or {})  File 
"/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 354, in 
_compiled_fn    raise QWebException("Error to render compiling 
AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], 
 encoding='unicode'), 
name)odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: 'NoneType' 
object is not callableTraceback (most recent call last):  File 
 "/opt/odoo12/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 347 in_compiled_fn   
 return compiled(self, append, new, options,log) 
File "<template>", line 1, in template_4549_24  
File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_23 File "<template>",line 3, in body_call_content_22

TypeError:'NoneType' object is not callable
    
Error to render compiling ASTTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callableTemplate: 4549Path: /templates/t/t/t/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tNode: <t t-foreach="sorted(vals)" t-as="o">
```

My code  to generate the report is as it follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <odoo>
   <data noupdate="0">

<template id="report_immunization">
<t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-call="web.basic_layout">
            <div class="header">
                <div style="width: 45%;float: left;">
                <img 
 src='/oeh_immunization/static/description/rva_logo.jpg' 
style="width:50%"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="page">
            
            
                <br/><br/><br/>
            <b><h3>Immunization Report</h3></b>        
            <br/>
                <b>Date Prepared:</b>
            
            <span t-esc="datetime.date.today().strftime('%B %d,%Y')"/><br/>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table table-condensed mt32">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:#909090;">
                            <th class="text-left">Vaccine Name</th>
                            <th class="text-left">Student's Name</th>
                            <th class="text-left">Dose Number</th>
                            <th class="text-left">Date <br/>Administered</th>
                            <th class="text-left">Next Due <br/>Date</th>
                            <!-- <th class="text-left">Administering<br/> Facility</th> -->
                            <th class="text-left">Clinician</th>
                            <!-- <th class="text-left">Adverse<br/> events <br/>observed?</th>
                            <th class="text-left">Adverse<br/> events<br/> reported<br/> to <br/>CDC<br/> VAERS?</th>
                            <th class="text-left">Observations</th> -->
                            <th class="text-left">On<br/> Schedule?</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
    
                    <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
                       <t t-foreach="sorted(vals)" t-as="o">
                           
                           <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p t-esc="o" class="m-0"/>
                                </td>
                                
                                <td>
                                    <p t-esc="vals[o][0]['patient']" class="m-0"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p t-esc="vals[o][0]['dose']" class="m-0"/>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <p t-esc="vals[o][0]['date']" class="m-0"/>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <p t-esc="vals[o][0]['next_due_date']" class="m-0"/>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <p t-esc="vals[o][0]['doctor']" class="m-0"/>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <p t-esc="vals[o][0]['on_schedule']" class="m-0"/>
                                </td>


                                </tr>


                                <t t-foreach="vals[o][1:]" t-as="i">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p t-esc="i['patient']" class="m-0"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p t-esc="i['dose']" class="m-0"/>
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <p t-esc="i['date']" class="m-0"/>
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <p t-esc="i['next_due_date']" class="m-0"/>
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <p t-esc="i['doctor']" class="m-0"/>
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <p t-esc="i['on_schedule']" class="m-0"/>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </t>

                            </t>
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table>
        
            
                <div class="oe_structure"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</t>
```

Comment: Did you define a custom QWEB model?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Qweb model is not defined i suppose

Comment: @sidharth  please show me how to do that.am stuck

Answer (score 0):

have you used this:-

```
<record id="project_task_template" model="ir.actions.report">
        <field name="name">Project Report</field>
        <field name="model">project.task</field>
        <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
        <field name="report_name">construction_management.task_invoice</field>
        <field name="report_file">construction_management.task_invoice</field>
        <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_project_task"/>
        <field name="binding_type">report</field>
    </record>
```

if so then please itrate docs over a for loop in your XML file :
after this  (t-call="web.basic_layout") like (t-foreach="docs" t-as='o')
and use (o.field_name) for example:

```
<t t-foreach="doc.move_ids_without_package" t-as="line">
    <p t-out="line.product_uom_qty"/>
    <p t-out="line.display_name"/>
    <p t-out="line.product_id.name"/>
    
    <t t-if="website_label_type == 'bsku'">
        <span t-out="line.product_id.bsku"/>
    </t>
    <t t-else="">
        <span t-out="line.product_id.asin"/>
    </t>
</t>
```